# how to creare a custom Action Bar with dropdown childs

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I need to create a custom action bar that will have some image buttons and on click they will drop down a menu list.

i have designed the action bar using a linear layout.

i have the controls attached in my main activity and and the click events handled, but i don't know how to create the drop down controls.

i want to position the the dropdown controls below the clicked button. how can i make all of this?

this is my code for the action bar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:background="#FFFFFF">
  <LinearLayout
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:background="@drawable/actionbar_background"
      android:layout_height="65dp">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btntest"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="Sup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btntest1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="Company"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button android:id="@+id/btntest2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
            android:text="Client"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with an action provider which can be used by ActionProvider class...

It replaces an action item with a customized layout, but it also takes control of all the item's behaviors.

besides taking the control of appearance of items it also handles default events for menu...

check the link for more information...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView